# We've always been at war with [standby]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Let's handle [standby](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/standby) like thought police: eradicate all traces and deny its existence.

---

I've just finished eradicating this tag from the conscious memory

Comment: Four legs good! Two legs bad!  (oops, wrong book!)

Comment: Despite your claim, I can still remember it. Oh wait... it's fading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All those in favor of Wonton Soup, upvote here. =]

Comment: This should be done. You can [status complete] whenever

Answer (score 3):

This is another one where I can see some argument for its existence ("primary server, standby server", "hot *standby*", etc.), but it seems entirely meta.
If nobody comes up with a good reason to save it I'm all for its wonton and violent destruction.

Comment: Is that wonton with rice noodles or egg noodles?

Comment: I'm feeling a bit wanton with my comments today.

Comment: @Ward Now I have to leave it like that forever so your comment makes sense! (fried Wontons, with rice noodles. If you ***must*** know. Throw them at the tag while they're still hot and dripping with boiling oil!)

Comment: I may be in the minority here, but I prefer fried wontons to wonton soup.

Comment: There are different qualities of wontons, and different soup bases, I sometime eat myself almost sick on decent wontons that I can buy and eat with rice noodles in a good, no-MSG broth.  mmmm, I know what I'm eating tonight...

Comment: Tell me more, sir.

Comment: @Ward Make sure you make enough soup to share with the rest of the rabble.

Comment: We use this stuff for all our bouillon needs: http://www.superiortouch.com/retail/products/better-than-bouillon/organic-bases  Chicken for stock for wonton w/ noodles, Beef for gravy for lamb or roast beef.

Comment: @Ward I'm a fan of [this stuff](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00153C4B4/ref=asc_df_B00153C4B41913202?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=asn&creative=395093&creativeASIN=B00153C4B4) myself -- also available in vegetable and beef (though nowhere near as compact).

Comment: @voretaq7 Yeah, I've used that brand and it's good.  Two good things about the Better than Bouillon stuff: Costco carries it, and for things like wonton, you can make the broth weak if you want.  The wontons give a lot of flavour to the soup, so the broth I make starts out quite weak, and never gets too salty.